# visual studio solution dependency windows phone 8

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

For my project I need to support windows phone 8.1, 8.1 silverlight, 8.0 silverlight, and 8.0.

The first 3 are maintainable in visual studio 2013 express for windows, where as the last one is only maintainable in visual studio 2012 express for windows 8. I have a portable library that handles the common code between the 4.

Unfortunately the portable library wont open in 2012, so the only way to import the library as a reference is through using the dll directly. Is there anyway to have visual studio 2012 open up a portable library project, so that it can build the dependency for the 8.0 library.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you get the Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition, it is free (as the Express editions you use are) and can handle all the type of projects.

Comment: I cant since, i work for an "enterprise" company and we haven't been afforded pro editions of visual studio.